# Filtering by variable to allow returning all rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have code like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
my_values <- rep(1:10, 10)
my_df <- data.frame(my_values, "points")

user_values <- c(2, 3)

filter(my_df, my_values %in% user_values)
```

The user provides certain values to filter by. In certain situations, the filter should not be "active", meaning rows with all values of "my_values" should be retained.

**What can I assign to `user_values` to achieve this?** I tried assigning NULL, but that returns 0 rows. Assigning TRUE coerces it to the value of 1.

I know I could assign `my_df$my_values` (or `unique(my_df$my_values)`), but filtering by that would probably take a long time when there are thousands of possible values for the variable to take. So I'm searching for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `TRUE` as it could be understood as "everything" semantically. `NULL` would be also an option as pointed out by @Konrad and eventually it breaks down to a matter of taste / overall conventions in your project:

```r
nrow(my_df)
# [1] 100

user_values <- c(2, 3)
my_df %>% 
   filter(isTRUE(user_values) | my_values %in% user_values) %>%
   nrow()
# [1] 20

user_values <- TRUE
my_df %>% 
   filter(isTRUE(user_values) | my_values %in% user_values) %>%
   nrow()
# [1] 100

user_values <- NULL
my_df %>% 
   filter(is.null(user_values) | my_values %in% user_values) %>%
   nrow()
# [1] 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` inside the `filter` function call:

```
filter(my_df, if(is.null(user_values)) TRUE else my_values %in% user_values)
```

Comment: @GKi Indeed, and the other answer shows this (and personally I also prefer it for readability reasons). However, if you write it that way, the `is.null(user_values)` value is going to get cycled `nrow(my_df)` times, which is what OP wants to avoid for efficiency reasons.

Comment: My read was that there is no concern about cycling per se, but about an unnecessary comparison like `my_values %in% unique(my_values)` which seems to be rather expensive for a noop aspecially when compared to `filter(rep(TRUE, n()))`.

Comment: @thothal Is it actually expensive though? I have no idea how `match` is actually implemented, and maybe it is actually inefficient, but I would hope that it’s implemented non-naïvely, in which case `my_values %in% unique(my_values)` should happen in *O* (*n* · log*n*), (compared to *O* (*n*) for comparing with a logical vector).

Comment: True, and while I would argue that *O (n) < O (n · logn)* (for  *n > 1* ;)), I would also agree that it is absolutely negligible.  Having said that, readability wise I would prefer `filter(TRUE)` over `filter(x %in% y)` because in the former case it is clear that we want all cases while for the second case we would need to know that `y == unique(x)`. The wording "rather expensive"  is misleading in this case,  and should be read as "unnecessary for a no-op".

Answer (score 0):

A possibility would be to test the `length` of `user_values`. If length is `0` then return all otherwise use `filter`.

```
if(length(user_values) > 0) filter(my_df, my_values %in% user_values) else my_df
```

Alternatively this could also be used inside `filter` like shown by @thothal.

```
filter(my_df, length(user_values) == 0 | my_values %in% user_values)
```

Or place the `if` condition inside `filter` as shown by @Konrad Rudolph.

```
filter(my_df, if(length(user_values) == 0) TRUE else my_values %in% user_values)
```

The following settings of `user_values` will give here all rows of `my_df`.

```
user_values <- c()
user_values <- logical()
user_values <- vector()
user_values <- character()
user_values <- numeric()
user_values <- NULL
```